# How to map through an object 2 levels deep

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map through an object that's 2 levels deep in react and I can't seem to get it working for the life of me.

Can anyone give me a lending hand?

```
 loadBeers() {
    const { userData } = this.props;
    if (userData.location) {
        Object.keys(userData.location).map(locationitem => {
            Object.keys(userData.location[locationitem].beer).map(beerItem => {
                return (
                    <BeerItem key={beerItem}>{userData.location[locationitem].beer[beerItem].beerName}</BeerItem>
                );
            });
        });
    } else {
        return 'hi';
    }
}
```

This is the object structure:

[image: the object structure as seen when logged in the browser]

Comment: What is the object structure? An example would provide more clarity.

Comment: Might be helpful if you add the object so people don't have to guess.

Comment: I've added that now, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something from your first `map()` call. If you don't the result of that map will just be an empty array. Also you don't seem to be returning the result of the maps, but maybe you're planning on doing something else with it:

```
loadBeers() {
    const { userData } = this.props;
    if (userData.location) {
       // also return result to original caller of loadBeers()
       return Object.keys(userData.location).map(locationitem => {
            /* Return something here from map callback */
            return Object.keys(userData.location[locationitem].beer).map(beerItem => {
                return (
                    <BeerItem key={beerItem}>{userData.location[locationitem].beer[beerItem].beerName}</BeerItem>
                );
            });
        });
    } else {
        return 'hi';
    }
}
```

Here's a paired down example with simple data:

```js
let userData = {location :{randoKey: {beer: {anotherweridKey:{ABV: 'some_abv',beerName: 'Bud',beerType: 'bad'}}}}}


let matrix
if (userData.location) {
  matrix = Object.keys(userData.location).map(locationitem => {
    return Object.keys(userData.location[locationitem].beer).map(beerItem => {
      return userData.location[locationitem].beer[beerItem].beerName
    });
  });
} else {
  console.log('hi');
}

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: Good catch Mark, I completely forgot about **return**